# how to automatically detect SURF feature of ROI of image(frame) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, surf, matlab-cvst

I want to compare frames of video that detect obstacle in path.for this work,  I use DetectSURFFeature which detect feature of each frame but I must to extract feature of Region of interest (ROI)  of image for obstacle detection. I am using MATLAB 2013a. this code exists in MATLAB 2014b. size of frame is 1200 x 900 and ROI is x=200 y=400 Width=200 Length=300

**question:**

how to automatically detect SURF feature of ROI of image(frame) in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

Simply crop the image and then use the SURF detector over the cropped image. :-)

In case you need help with cropping,

I_cropped=I_original(200:400,400:700,:);

Now, use the SURF detector on I_cropped.

Answer (score 0):

The `detectSURFFeatures` function now takes an optional ROI input.